# htaccess rewriteCond ignored

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want all traffic redirected from app.foo.bar.com to maintenance.foo.bar.com, except urls containing the string api, ref/mail and track.php.

```
#maintenance routing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !api
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !ref/mail
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !track.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(?:admin\.)?(?:app\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://maintenance.%1/ [QSA,L]

# basic framework routing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This is not working.

Working example:

Example url: `http://app.foo.bar.com/`

Result: `http://maintenance.foo.bar.com/`

Not working example:

Example url: `http://app.foo.bar.com/api/objects?token=foobarfoobarfoobar`

Result: `http://maintenance.foo.bar.com/?url=api/objects&token=foobarfoobarfoobar`

What's missing or wrong?

Comment: According to https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ this simply appears to be your “basic framework routing” section kicking in …?

Comment: According to htaccess.madewithlove.be the result is `http://app.foo.bar.com/index.php?url=api/objects&token=foobarfoobarfoobar`. Is 'index.php?url=api/..' why it gets redirected to maintenance? 'api' is still in the url

Comment: `REQUEST_URI` is the _path_ segment of the requested URL only. `http://app.foo.bar.com/index.php?url=api/…` does not have `api` in the URL path, it only has it inside the query string.

Comment: That.... seems to be fixing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !api` to solve the problem. At the result, 'api' is in the query string instead of the request uri.